# Test for uniform distribution with multiple participants

Tags: chi-squared-test, uniform-distribution

I know how to use e.g. the Chi-Square test to check whether data are uniformly distributed. I was wondering whether the approach changes if the data comes from multiple participants, i.e., there is a **grouping variable**.

Completely arbitrary example: Say we want to check whether different pizza types (which I treat as mutually exclusive) are ordered according to a uniform distribution. We can count how often each pizza has been ordered, but the orders come from four different customers. Each of them orders a different amount of pizza, and you can see that some of them order more "uniformly" than others. Here is some code to create example data in `R`:

```r
pizza <- 
  data.frame(
    customer = c("Jenny", "Peter", "Dan", "Lucy"),
    pepperoni = c(10, 2, 12, 25),
    mushrooms = c(10, 1, 4, 2),
    hawaii = c(10, 3, 10, 40)
  )
```

```r
  customer pepperoni mushrooms hawaii
1    Jenny        10        10     10
2    Peter         2         1      3
3      Dan        12         4     10
4     Lucy        25         2     40
```

Would I just create the sum for each pizza type and run a Chi-Square? Or is there a way to acknowledge that the data are grouped within customers, who contribute a different amount of data points and might show different distributions (similar to e.g. a mixed model)?
In this example, it's only four customers, but in my real world example, it's > 100 participants.

Comment: In your pizza example, you forgot to include *vegetarian*. Then, your customer base certainly will include some vegetarians, and you **know** without testing that the distribution is not uniform ...

Comment: "Would I just create the sum for each pizza type and run a Chi-Square?" - That'd ignore the dependence of orders within a single customer. However (1) I'm not aware of a straightforward alternative approach (probably one could construct something using ideas such as bootstrap), and (2) assuming that the distribution *within a single customer* is not necessarily uniform, it would be rather extraordinary to think that the overall distribution could be uniform. So some thought about what hypothesis makes sense to test here is also required.

Comment: Following on the comment by @ChristianHennig:  it would be better if you told us your real application, only then can we discuss what should be the appropriate hypothesis

Comment: Actually, the real application isn't much different from the example. It's a bunch of participants each selecting one of four categories in multiple trials, but each participant has a different number of trials. What I want to check is whether the four categories are chosen equally often. As @ChristianHennig said, it gets tricky when different participants show different distributions. Which is exactly why I was wondering whether something similar to a mixed model exists, where you get both a group level effect, but also the deviation from that effect per group (i.e., participant).

Comment: Is uniformity of real interest here? What do you learn by testing it?

Comment: Yes, it is of interest. In principle, participants knew that the categories were equally distributed, so you would expect them to pick each category equally often. If they don't, that means they did not use that information for some reason, violating our assumption about the distribution of the answers. (What different response patterns would reflect is an entirely different question. But in principle, my question still stands: Is it possible to test for uniformity across a sample that is grouped? Irrespective of my use case, I am interested to know.)